# remove char from string with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to remove a period '.' from a value that comes from a feed, however I don't really want to do this in my app.js, rather in my view.

So if I do the following:

```
 value: {{item.v_value}}
```

I get 3.5, I'd simply like to strip out and render out 35 instead.

So basically reusing the replace function - but on the item value only.

Comment: Is `v_value` a string or a number?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use `replace`:

If `v_value` is a string:

```
value: {{item.v_value.replace('.', '')}}
```

If `v_value` is a number, "cast" it to a string first:

```
value: {{(item.v_value + '').replace('.', '')}}
```

Basically, you can use JavaScript in those brackets.

Comment: It almost works for me, I needed to replace all occurrences of that 'dot' so I had to perform a global replacement (\g) and escape the '.' character, like so: 
{{item.v_value.replace(/\./g, '')}}

Answer (score 7):

If you need it to be reusable you can use a filter.

```
myApp.filter('removeString', function () {
    return function (text) {
        var str = text.replace('thestringtoremove', '');
        return str;
    };
});
```

Then in your HTML you can something like this:

```
value: {{item.v_value | removeString}}
```